# Number recognition from Image java

Tags: java, image, find

I have image, and I have the number on it. 
I exactly know coordinates start and end of the number, and I can save all different digits in advance. 
I want to understand what is the number it. i.e I want to get variable of type int. 
I invented stupid algorithm:find each digit -> sort them and translate to the int, but I think it's very long and not optimal) 
do you have good ideas or library ? I didn't find it. 
sorry for my very bad english:(

Comment: show us your code so we can improve it

Comment: I don't have code still,sorry) I only think that I will write)

Comment: `I invented stupid algorithm` -> go ahead and write it

Comment: Or describe the algorithm, in pseudo code or even English.

Comment: Save all digits on the computer. Then you find all digits in the area of the number. Then you sort them on the coordinate X, and print it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can go two ways, one is datamining you train a classifier with the the numbers you created in advance which must work properly because it will be an exact matchin, but that's very heavy weight and probably a bad idea :)

The way I would go is to separate a sequence of indexes that will correctly identifies a number, meaning that you should try to select the smallest group of pixels that is different in all digits.

An example would be that insetad of numbers you just have 4 black and white pixels that you have to categorize into 3 buckets

1 is 
|b|w|w|b
2 is
|b|b|w|b
3 is
|b|w|b|w

you see that here the 2 and third characters decide the which bucket you put your input into so given the input a you just have to check the 2 and 3 pixel against all your possible inputs. Also you can incorporate the idea from the [KMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) algorithm for textual pattern matching